# Can my Korean wife visit me before we apply for her spousal visa later?

Tags: visas, uk

I am British and married a Korean girl while living in Korea for many years. I returned to the UK this year and I'm just now starting a job, so once I have been earning the required amount for 6 months, we will be applying for her spousal visa.

But she came to visit me for 1 week recently and has since decided she wants to spend the next 6 months with me here on a visiting visa, after which she will return to Korea so we can apply for her spousal visa.

I am wondering if her coming back on a visiting visa and living with me would affect our spousal visa application later on? We really don't want to spend the next 6 months apart but we are worried about causing troubles for the spousal visa later on. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Your wife has already successfully applied for a visit visa as your wife, which must be a positive. Does she still have the same ties to her home country? The spousal visa is judged on different criteria so the bigger, more immediate, concern may be that with a proposed visit of 6 months and a husband in the U.K. she may be seen as a flight risk.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. She didn't apply for visit visa when she came that week, as Korean she has a visa waiver for the UK and wasn't asked any questions upon entry then. My only concern is that her coming to stay with me for 6 months or less will hurt our spousal visa application when we come to do it after me working for 6 months.